# How do I get Row Totals using QUERY() in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with the following [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s8krJ7rbZ1DMblZ3vdLcG5pySVM3ESCBy1o7R5Zv4LM/edit#gid=237012432).

`Sheet2` uses the following `QUERY()` function to retrieve data from `Sheet1`

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1s8krJ7rbZ1DMblZ3vdLcG5pySVM3ESCBy1o7R5Zv4LM", "Sheet1!B3:D"))`

Is it possible to return the Row Totals (*For Example:* `B4+C4+D4` *for Row 4*) using the above `QUERY()` function?

Please Advise.

*My Query and Expected Output are Outlined on the Google Sheet.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1s8krJ7rbZ1DMblZ3vdLcG5pySVM3ESCBy1o7R5Zv4LM", "Sheet1!B3:D"), "Select Col1+Col2+Col3 label Col1+Col2+Col3 ''")
```

Note that importing from another tab in the same spreadsheet doesn't require importrange. In that case, this should also work:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B3:D, "Select B+C+D label B+C+D ''")
```

Another way, to achieve the same result would be

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(Sheet1!B3:B), Mmult(--Sheet1!B3:D, transpose(column(Sheet1!B2:D2)^0)),))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just using `IMPORTRANGE()` to replicate the original query function

Comment: Would you mind explaining this part `label Col1+Col2+Col3 ''` so I can accept your answer

Comment: That part removes (or better: replaces with an empy value) the label sum(sum()) that is automatically generated because of the summing in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that while a simple QUERY can return the results, it will actually take up the entire column if you don't limit it. In other words, all the null rows from Sheet1! B:D will also come over with the QUERY. If you want only the results that have numbers, try something like this:

`=QUERY(Sheet1!B3:D, "Select B+C+D WHERE B+C+D is not null label B+C+D ''")`

Or you could use MMULT like this:

`=MMULT(FILTER(Sheet1!B3:D,Sheet1!B3:B<>""),SEQUENCE(3,1,1,0))`

The results may look the same whether limited or not. But in a QUERY or MMULT without limitations, you won't be able to use the space below the visible results for anything. I only mention this because, currently in your sheet, you *do* have data (a TRANSPOSE formula) below the main results. If you won't in your real sheet and don't care about the are below the visible results being inaccessible to other data or formula entry, then you don't need to limit.